# How to make confidence interval of linear combination of regression estimator in R?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

In this regression:

[image]

I know `confit()` from the package glht can do confidence interval of every estimator.

But how to make confidence interval of a linear combination of coefficients, 
such as confidence interval of β3+2*β5 in R?

Added this

[image]

Comment: Oh sorry I just saw that you are using glht. Ok we can use that. Next time include that in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `linearHypothesis` in the `car` package:

```
library(car)

dat <- data.frame(
  y = rnorm(100),
  x1 = rnorm(100),
  x2 = rnorm(100)
)

fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = dat)

# enter linear hypothesis as a matrix
linearHypothesis(fit, t(c(0,2,2)), 0)
# enter linear hypothesis as a string
linearHypothesis(fit, "2*x1 + 2*x2 = 0")
```

Or with `glht` in the `multcomp` package, which also provides a confidence interval for the linear combination:

```
library(multcomp)

lh <- glht(fit, linfct = t(c(0,2,2)))
confint(lh)
# Linear Hypotheses:
#        Estimate lwr     upr    
# 1 == 0  0.1258  -0.4398  0.6914
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have sample but not created by data.frame, which means the regression is '''a = lm(A$y ~ A$x_1 + A$x_2 + A$x_3 + A$x_4 + A$x_5)''', then why '''linearHypothesis(a, "x_3 + 2*x_5 = 0")''' will appear " Error in constants(lhs, cnames_symb) : " ?

Comment: @user265349 Anyway `car::linearHypothesis` does not provide a confidence interval (I misread your question). Use a dataframe or use a matrix.

Comment: OK, can you please to see the picture I edited and tell me am I right?

Comment: @user265349 You can also do `glht(fit, linfct = "x_3+2*x_5==0")`. But this requires to have a dataframe, I think.